# error caused by procedure application

Tags: scheme, racket

Here is the code:

```
(define test1DataA '(("a" "a") ("b" "b") ("c" "c") ("d" "d") ("e" "ok")))
(define test1DataB '(("a" "aa") ("b" "bb") ("c" "cc") ("d" "dd") ("ok" "Ir OK!")))

(define manageFirstList (lambda (a b) (append a b)))

(define ff (lambda (a b) (manageFirstList (a b))))

(ff test1DataA test1DataB)
```

And here is the error message:

> procedure application: expected procedure, given: '(("a" "a") ("b"
>   "b") ("c" "c") ("d" "d") ("e" "ok")); arguments were: '(("a" "aa")
>   ("b" "bb") ("c" "cc") ("d" "dd") ("ok" "Ir OK!"))

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

`(manageFirstList(a b))))`

Why are there parens around `a b`? `a` isn't a function. If you want to apply `manageFirstList` to `a b`, then do `(manageFirstList a b)`.